# Error when returning flash.jsonify() in Flask App

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, jsonify

**Background:**
I'm building a basic flask app, that will allow me to return a Collection from a  Atlas Compass Cluster and then use the Collection data to create an HTML container to display the data **and** create some D3 charts.

**Issue:**
I've created two `@app.route`, to allow me to visualize how both `json.dump` and `flask.jsonify` return data, before I decide which to use
 Unfortunately whilst my `json.dump` route returns the data (via an index.html page), my jsonify doesn't seem to work.. I get the following error returned in my Terminal

**Error:**
`TypeError: jsonify() behavior undefined when passed both args and kwargs`

**Code:**
Here is my code, which shows both **@app.route**

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId, json_util
import json

cluster = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://group2:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.mpjcg.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["simply_recipe"]
collection = db["recipes_collection"]

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/recipes", methods=["GET"])
def get_recipes():
    all_recipes = list(collection.find({}))
    return json.dumps(all_recipes, default=json_util.default)

@app.route("/recipes_jsonify", methods=["GET"])
def get_recipes_jsonify():
    all_recipes = list(collection.find({}))
    return flask.jsonify(all_recipes, default=json_util.default)
```

I'm a complete beginner with Flask, so no doubt I have missed something obvious, **can anyone help?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue; i was able to fix it by using

> data=

Keyword arguments: Treated as a dict of values.
jsonify(data=data, errors=errors) is the same as jsonify({"data": data, "errors": errors}).
see below ..

```html
@app.route("/recipes_jsonify", methods=["GET"])
def get_recipes_jsonify():
    all_recipes = list(collection.find({}))
    return flask.jsonify(data=all_recipes, default=json_util.default)
```

Answer (score -2):

here have a look at this example, which explaines how jsonify can handle your data:

```
 from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/_get_current_user')
def get_current_user():
    return jsonify(username=g.user.username,
                   email=g.user.email,
                   id=g.user.id)
```

Output:

```
{
"username": "admin",
"email": "admin@localhost",
"id": 42
}
```

Source: https://www.kite.com/python/docs/flask.jsonify